# Are questions asking for a mathematical formula on-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31789649/custom-weighted-scale) which only has the [math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/math) tag, and is clearly asking for a mathematical formula unrelated to any programming language specifically.

I could not find an appropriate close reason in the off-topic section, nor could I vote to migrate it to [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/) where I believe it belongs, so what should be done?

The user seems to have asked other weighted algorithm requests such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732028/special-weighted-sorting-needed-in-sql/31732410) which I'm also not sure is worth keeping open.

Comment: It's either too broad, or you could just make a custom reason that points at [math.se].  Make sure it *is* on topic there first.

Comment: I posted a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31789649/custom-weighted-scale#comment51509980_31789649) notifying the OP that their question is being discussed here.

Comment: It's odd that they wouldn't say which language they were working with.

Comment: The math question does not seem like it was researched, or the OP tried anything.

Comment: They're actually the same question.  The newer question is OP trying to understand the solution to the older question.  The fact that he can't understand the answer to the older question indicates that he needs more help than just "I'm in need of a formula".

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I do not think that this question would be well received at [the Math site](http://math.stackexchange.com), because it is not about a mathematical question, but on its implementation in a language.

After reading the (now accepted) answer, I do not think it is even too broad. I admit it can be unclear, because I really needed to read the answer and its comments to understand what OP really asked.

But like many implementation questions for a simple algorithm, it is almost language agnostic: once you read an implementation in one language, it is trivial to translate it in any other language you know.

My opinion on that:

- It is a poor question, and the [math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/math) tag is specially bad => I would have preferred [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm) and [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) or even better [pseudocode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pseudocode)
- It should contain some examples of input values with the expected output so that reader can make sure he has correctly understood the question
- But it really does not deserve to be closed as *too broad*
- And please do not throw such questions on [the Math site](http://math.stackexchange.com): it would be totally off-topic there.

Comment: I think "its implementation in a language" and "language-agnostic" argue against each other.  Either OP is trying to convert a formula to a particular language, or (here) OP is trying to convert some words into a formula.

Comment: "I want this formula implemented in any language" seems like it's *too broad* to me, personally. There's a huge number of potential answers to that question; at the very least it needs to be narrowed down to a single language.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist : For me it is (almost) clear : OP accepts any language implementation and will convert it in its own prefered language. In that case, the best answers would be pseudo-code - maybe `pseudocode`  would be better than `language-agnostic`

Answer (score 20):

The algorithm part isn't the problem here.  The help center states that asking about software algorithms *is* on topic.

The problem is the question is essentially a requirements dump and a request to "do it for me".  Hence, too broad was used as a close reason.  I could also see "unclear what you are asking" being used because reading that left me scratching my head.  After a few read-thrus, I kinda get what he wants, but there is a lot of vagueness in how he needs it achieved (linear decay over time, sine wave, pick random numbers as long as the last one meets his requirement, etc.) and why.

Long story short, algorithms are on-topic (as long as they conform to the other guidelines for asking questions).  "Do my work for me given these somewhat vague requirements" aren't.