# Should a question about finding the largest inscribed chord of a closed polyline be open?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/16754262

This one just came up in the re-open queue, and I selected "Leave closed" - which was apparently wrong.

Yes, I think it's an interesting question. And it's about algorithms which makes it relevant to SO.

*BUT* it is asking for recommendations "Can you suggest an efficient algorithm for this?" which is one reason for closing it.

It is also fairly broad, another reason for closing.

You have to trust the review queue system to a degree. If it's presented to as having been closed, and you agree with the purported reason, then "Leave Closed" is a reasonable response IMHO.

And this one potentially belongs on another site (software-engineering, or even maths)

And, finally, there's this: [Do I need to read the answers when voting to close?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227037/do-i-need-to-read-the-answers-when-voting-to-close/227044#227044)

I think questions like this, where it's a pure judgement call, need to be trimmed from the audit queue.

It's getting so I have an itch to click on every question in a separate tab to see if I'm being set up.

Comment: I'd have a bit of difficulty classifying an algorithm as an "off-site resource".

Comment: Yes, but the most likely response would be a link to paper or site describing the algorithm. Anyway, for the moment I've VTC'd to (hopefully) stop it turning up in anyone else's queue - and, of course, because I actually think it should be closed.

Comment: @Shog9 Alternative question title "Should requests for algorithms be off-topic?" Might be a little more generic. I think my main problem is that this one is not clear cut - hence probably shouldn't be in the audit list.

Comment: *Yes, but the most likely response would be a link to paper or site describing the algorithm.* Linking to a paper or third party site isn't against the rules (unless it's a link only answer or spam). We can't explicitly ask for off-site resources but that doesn't mean we can't ask any question where an off-site resource might be part of an answer.

Comment: Don't worry about failed review audits, the audit system is inherently broken. I myself recently caught a ban for this: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16750174 The automatic audits simply don't work, but I have given up complaining about this... I'll just take the fails/bans and wait, until someone fixes the audit system. Audit questions have to be chosen manually, I do not see another way to get this fixed properly

Answer (score 6):

"Algorithm" is such a fancy word; using it immediately makes whatever you're trying to do sound complicated and precise. You probably wouldn't go around talking about your algorithm for an Old Fashioned Whiskey Cocktail, but *if you did* I'll bet folks would think you were one hell of a mixologist.

The downside, of course, is that when someone thinks you're sending them off on a search for the holy grail instead of asking for directions to the bar they might decide that the scope of your quest is beyond what they can offer assistance with.

So I recommend mentally replacing "algorithm" with some less expensive words when you see it. Maybe "steps" or "HOWTO" or "What would a poor schlub like me need to do..."

Let's try it: "What would a poor schlub like me need to do to find the largest inscribed chord of a closed polyline?"

Seems like a more reasonable question, eh?

#### See also:

- [Is it okay to just ask for an algorithm to a problem?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271842/is-it-okay-to-just-ask-for-an-algorithm-to-a-problem)
- [High-level algorithm/engineering questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345467/high-level-algorithm-engineering-questions)
- [Are questions asking for a mathematical formula on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300689/are-questions-asking-for-a-mathematical-formula-on-topic)

Comment: To be fair, OP is struggling seeing how that question is relevant to a programmer. Yeah, you could program something to solve the problem, but are you, as programmer, essential to be able to reach the solution?

Comment: What would a poor schlub like me need to do to get an Old Fashioned Whiskey Cocktail 'round these here parts?

Comment: Actually your "poor schlub" question sounds like a "gimme teh algorithm" question...

Comment: Interestingly, the linked questions seem to lean towards "too broad", with a touch of "judgement call".