# Should this math related question be moved to Math.StackExchange?

Tags: discussion, support, migration

I came across this question while reviewing First Posts:

*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45644755/solved-coupled-sde-using-milstein-method*

It is essentially asking for help solving for two mathematical formulas. It was in pretty bad shape when I got to it, and I have suggested an edit that I think makes it an acceptable question, but not for Stack Overflow. I was going to try to flag it for moving to Math.StackExchange, but I can't do so.

**Related:** *[Are questions asking for a mathematical formula on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300689/are-questions-asking-for-a-mathematical-formula-on-topic)*

Based on this Meta post and reading the Math homepage, I believe the question meets the wickets for migration after the edit is approved. Should it be migrated or just closed as off topic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should not be migrated. We have a rule of ["don't migrate crap."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) Migrating this would violate that rule.

## The Question

The question on the main site has been deleted. So, here it is for under-10k users, as edited by the OP here on Meta:

> I have a coupled 2 degree SDE that I don't know how to solve for. They are
>
> (X)''= -(alpha1).(x)'+(beta1).cos(Y).sin(X)+F1+W1
> (Y)''= -(alpha2).(Y)'+(beta2).cos(X).sin(Y)+F2+W2
>
> - F1, F2 are constants
> - W1, W2 are stochastic functions of time and no correlation with others also
> - alpha and beta are constant
>
> How do I solve these?

Let's leave aside the numerous problems that your edit left in place and the crummy formatting; we'll focus on whether the question is salvagable.

## What's the Rule?

Now let's look at the guidance in [the Meta SE post that I linked above](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work):

> **Don't migrate crap!** Ever. If the question is likely to be closed or deleted on the destination site anyway, don't bother migrating it. Just vote to close it normally and advise the OP of the other site in the comments. If they decide to improve the question, then they can go post it over there, or they can edit their question so it's on-topic on the original site.

## So, What Should We Do with *this* Question?

This question was, frankly, crap. It's basically this:

> I don't know how to do my homework, and I don't have any work to show what I've tried.
>
> Here it is. Please do it for me.

That won't go over well on any SO/SE site. Also, note this guidance from [that Meta SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work):

> **Be familiar with the destination site.** If you have never even visited the destination site before, read through its about page and help center thoroughly and make sure the question actually belongs there. Don't just look at the name of a site and automatically assume that the question can be asked there. Each site has its own rules, and rules vary greatly across sites.

I notice you're not a member on Math.SE. You don't *have* to be a member of a site to recommend migration, but it's unlikely that you would be familiar with the target site's standards if you're not a member. In this case, this question would get shot down pretty hard. See the [recently closed questions on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=closed%3Ayes), which is a veritable graveyard of "please do my homework" questions.

Comment: Well, I feel kind of bad for even posting now after the rain of negativity. Your answer was very thorough though, thank you. I see now where the original asker could have improved his question for the other site.

Comment: I do want to ask though, you mentioned my edit left a lot to be desired and I don't see it. Are you talking about the equation formatting? I know it's not as fancy as Math.SE equation formatting, but I still think it's perfectly legible and I can tell exactly what the equations are supposed to be doing. How could the edit have been improved?

Comment: @SandPiper don't feel bad about asking! If you don't know something and can't find the answer, you should always ask here on Meta. Keep in mind that downvotes on Meta don't mean the same thing as on Main. They may mean that people think you didn't do enough research, or, in this instance, they may just mean that people are voting, "No, don't migrate it." Don't take them personally.

Comment: @SandPiper about your edit: it fixed a few grammatical and syntax problems, but it left a few in place. For example, the first sentence is wrong; there shouldn't be a "for" there. In the bullet points, the phrase "and no correlations with others also" is wrong and should be "and uncorrelated with each other" or something similar. The functions should probably be formatted as code (since we don't have MathJax on this site). Please note: I approved your edit. It wasn't a *bad* edit. It's that, when there are as many problems with a post as there were here, you have to ask, "Can this be fixed?"

Answer (score 2):

Is this a question that is going to brighten the day of Math.SE users?

No, it doesn't look like one. Please don't migrate crap.

Comment: I agree with not migrating crap, that's why I edited it first. However, asking if it will brighten their day is like asking if any given question here will brighten your day. I browsed Math.SE and almost all of the questions I looked at looked just like this. "I have this math problem, how do I solve it?" It sounded to me like it was very on topic there.

Comment: @SandPiper If you look more closely, you'll see that questions that go over well are those that show some effort, where the OP got stuck on a specific, clearly-stated problem. Questions that are pure homework dumps do *not* go over well.